# Can the hreflang attribute be used with videos?

Tags: html, video, hyperlink

Can the hreflang attribute be used to define the language of linked videos with talking in them? Or should it only used when linking to documents that contain text?

```html
<a href="video.mp4" hreflang="en" type="video/mp4" download>Download Video</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter anyway since it's purely advisory and browsers shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: But it's good for search engines.

Comment: You lost me at search engines.

Comment: Google yahoo and bing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Google yahoo and bing?

Yep, all of those. One should really be coding for people and the sake of good content. But let me give an answer anyway. Yes, it can be used, the spec says it is applicable to links - `a` and `area` included. Besides that, it's valid in HTML5 (which would be needed with `video`).

> user agents must use only language information associated with the resource to determine its language, not metadata included in the link to the resource.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html